# UIActionSheet changes values of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet

I've encountered what I think might be a bug, but I'm not completely sure. So I'm asking you in case you know of a fix.

Basically I have a `UIScrollView` that dynamically changes size based on the number of `UITextFields`. It starts out at one size (one textfield), and then as more is added, the contentsize of the scrollview increases. This works fine. However, when a user taps a button that opens a `UIActionSheet`, the contentsize sets to 0. This makes the scrollview not scrollable when he later dismisses the actionsheet. I placed an `NSLog` statement to check the contentsize of the scrollview before and after the actionsheet is presented, and it goes from whatever (for example 360) to 0.

However, this does not happen when I use a `UIAlertView` instead. If there isn't a fix for this problem, an alertview is my backup solution. I'd prefer an actionsheet though, as it fits the task better.

I hope someone out there knows what might be causing this and how I can fix it.

Thanks!

**As per request, here is some relevant code:**

Code for opening the actionsheet:

```
- (IBAction)addImage:(id)sender {
  UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take a picture", @"Choose from photo album", nil];
  [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Here's how I edit the value of the scrollView after a new textfield has been added:

```
CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(anotherTextField.frame);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

(Note the `anotherTextField.frame` will be the location of the new textfield. So something like 40 - 80 - 120 - 160 etc.)

---

Here's the `viewDidLoad`: (I don't have a `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
  CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(self.textField2.frame);
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy, I added some code. I didn't quite know what to add, as my entire document is several hundred lines. This is the most relevant I could think of, since the value of the `UIScrollView` resets when the `UIActionSheet` has been opened.

Comment: Is this on iPhone, iPad or both?  Can you post your viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear for the view that contains your scrollview?

Comment: This goes for both. I don't have a `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`, but I will post the `viewDidLoad`, as it is there I initially set the scrollview to the height of one (the first) textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your `UIScrollView`'s contentSize is set by an `NSLayoutConstraint`. Then an `UIActionSheet` causes the constraints to "refresh"...

**Edit:**

Notice any warnings in interface builder? It usually tells you when the constraints won't be able to find a usable content size for the `UIScrollView`. It's actually a pretty complicated issue, this specific issue with `UIScrollView` and constraints. I usually do this through code.

The best way here, as you set the contentSize through code anyway, is to just set your `UIScrollView`'s contentSize in the `UIViewController`'s `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` message.

So instead of

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
  CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(self.textField2.frame);
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Have it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Any other code here...
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
  CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(self.textField2.frame);
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Or override `updateViewConstraints` the same way as a last resort...

Comment: I'm not so familiar with iOS development, so I'm not 100% sure what you're talking about. But I have set constraints on the scrollview in the storyboard, so it fits both a 3.5 and 4 inch screen. 

If this is the problem, how would I solve it?

Comment: Notice any warnings in interface builder? It usually tells you when the constraints won't be able to find a usable content size for the UIScrollView. It's actually a pretty complicated issue, this specific issue with UIScrollView and constraints. I usually do this through code.

Comment: There are sadly no errors or warnings anywhere.. :(

Comment: I tried your suggestion but sadly it did not make a difference :( Do you know of any other possible solutions? Especially considering that the problem doesn't occur with alertviews?

Comment: We need to figure out what causes the "refresh" of the constraints, and trigger the reset of the contentSize there. You could try doing the same thing to `updateViewConstraints`.
Also - please check if the UIScrollView's by any chance grew in height!

Comment: So it did actually make a difference. Before your change, the height of the scrollview was **0** after the actionsheet. Now it is **50** (the height of one textfield).

Comment: The height or the content size? :-)
You need to make sure the the *height* is enough size to show the content, but not taller than the screen. And the the *contentSize.height* represents the content's height.

Comment: I meant contentsize all the time, sorry. I never change the height of the scrollview. That's laid out in the storyboard :)

Comment: No, sadly :( The problem still persists. The contentsize of the scrollview resets when the actionsheet is opened, so the scrollview is no longer scrollable when the actionsheet is dismissed. I will try to set the values in the methods you told me about to see if that fixes it :)

Comment: Ok, so that actually solved it! I'm storing the tag of the latest textfield in a variable, so in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I just set the contentsize to the height of the textfield with that tag. And then I set the first textfield in the `viewWillAppear`. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome! I was in the process of moving servers in 3am, and had to do *something* to kill time ;-)